# trying to display 4 cards at a time in a one carousel page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, carousel

I am trying to make a slider for my card component. but the problem is I am not able to display them in a proper manner.

I tried setting the width of `Carousel inner` from `100%` to `25%` but That increases the number of pages in the carousel and shows blank pages when data from my API runs out.
I want to loop through the data from API and did not want any extra blank pages at the end of the carousel.

providing the link for codesandbox [Here is the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-grass-15yook?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: try refreshing the IDE if it shows dependency error regarding Roboto font,

Answer (score 0):

To make a loop, You can reset the active index to 0 again. Therefore the updateIndex function should be like,

```
const updateIndex = (newIndex) =>{
        if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= React.Children.count(children)) {
            newIndex = 0;
        } 
        setActiveIndex(newIndex);
    };
```

Carousel.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Carousel.css";

export const CarouselItem = ({ children, width }) => {
  return (
    <div className="carousel-item" style={{ width: width }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Carousel = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  const updateIndex = (newIndex) => {
    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= React.Children.count(children)) {
      newIndex = 0;
    }
    setActiveIndex(newIndex);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="carousel">
        <div
          className="inner"
          style={{ transform: `translateX(-${activeIndex * 100}%)` }}
        >
          {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { width: "100%" });
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="indicators">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            updateIndex(activeIndex - 1);
          }}
        >
          Prev
        </button>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
          return (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                updateIndex(index);
              }}
            ></button>
          );
        })}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            updateIndex(activeIndex + 1);
          }}
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: the problem is not only the loop thing but the proper rendering of cards
If I am setting ```activeIndex``` to 100% then it is showing only one card per page, nd after changing it to 25% it creates mulitple pages equal to the cards

Comment: Change the style properties. (`{ width: "100%" }` and `translateX(-${activeIndex * 100}%)` )

Comment: Can you provide your expected outcome?

Comment: [link](https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view ) you can visit this link